# Angular 6 Post form to new tab

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out how to set a target on a form in angular. I want the submission of the form to happen in a new tab so I have the below.

```
<form id="formLanding" role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #landingForm="ngForm" [target]="'_blank'">
...
</form>
```

However, angular doesn't post this to a new tab. I have read about noNgForm but this doesn't work for my use case as I already have a ton of work done that ties into Angular's form validation and this directive removes the form refernce. Does anyone know how to post a form to a new tab while still using Angular forms?

Comment: A new tab meaning?

Comment: a new browser tab. What I want to happen is submit the form into a new tab. So that I can change the content of the original tab. Basically, I am trying to prevent pop up blockers from blocking a new tab but the only way to do that is to post into a new tab

Comment: Opening it in a new tab means it has to load the angular app again, i don't think this will unblock the ad

Comment: Yes it would have to reload in the new tab but this is expected. It is not an add blocking issue. It is a pop up blocker issue. When calls to window.open are made, popup blockers stop them. One way around this is to post to a new tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright it isn't pretty but this is a requirement I can not get around. Here is how I solved.

Create another form element that will open a form in a new page with a get request (pop up blockers can not block form loads so this works)

```
<form  ngNoForm #htmlForm hidden action="{{window?.location?.href}}" method="get" target="_blank">
  <input name="zip" value="{{formData.zipCode}}"/>
  <input name="autoSubmit" value="true"/>
</form>
```

This will open the page you are currently on in a new tab with the form values as query params. Then in your component you can get a reference to the form

```
@ViewChild("htmlForm")
htmlForm: ElementRef;
```

and in your click handler for the angular managed form you can do what ever logic you need plus

```
this.htmlForm.nativeElement.submit();
```

Then on the init of the component you can read these form values and automatically submit.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (params && params.autoSubmit) {

        this.formData.zipCode = params.zip;
        //submit this.formData to the server. 
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The crucial bit that did it for me was the `ngNoForm` attribute in the form element. This disables Angular's additional form processing and lets it work as a regular raw HTML form.